# Merge two or more overlayed "Drainage Direction" rasters calculated with r.watershed command

Tags: grass-gis, merge

I have a big raster and I need to calculate catchment areas with GRASS command (r.watershed, r.water.outlet) but I can't process it due to its weight.

In order to solve that problem I've divided the Raster into several ones overlaying the edges and I've elaborated the rasters one by one using the GRASS sequence obtaining Drainage Directions and the stream flows.
The problem is that, when I try to merge them back together (Drain rasters and Stream Rasters) and I use the r.water.outlet command, the catchment areas delineation stops in the border of the raster.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please edit your question and add which GRASS GIS version you use, on which operating system and what "big raster" map means precisely (rows and columns?).